# Join a sql table with excel file goes wrong

Tags: join, merge, ssis

It has been a long time I used SSIS.

I try to join a sql table & an excel file. 
The table has Category attribute in english.
The excel file has english category attribute & dutch category attribute.
I want to change the value of the sql table category attribute from english into the dutch version. 
The destination is a new sql table with all the fields/attributes of the first sql table but the values of category attribute are in dutch.

I tried many times with merge join, union all and the join component but it fails many times.
Maybe I'm doing someting wrong.
Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Use the Merge Join component.

Before connecting your Excel Source and SQL Source make sure that the English Category column from both sources is A) The same datatype and B) Sorted by that column.  Both inputs to a Merge Join MUST be sorted.  Once sorted, connect your sources into the Merge Join.  It will look something like this, Except with an Excel file on one side.

[image]

Sort both sources by Enlgish_Column and they will be detected as the join key for your Merge Join component.